# Include regular JS file in a react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking to include [this](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) plugin in my react project. It seems to be installed the old-skool way, i.e. using script tags. Does anyone know how to to this? My project hierarchy is as follows:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── components
│   ├── containers
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── global-styles.css
│   ├── global-styles.js
│   ├── i18n.js
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── reducers.js
│   ├── routes.js
│   ├── store.js
│   ├── tests
│   ├── translations
│   └── utils
├── appveyor.yml
├── Changelog.md
├── cloudformation-templates
│   ├── app-stack.json
│   └── static-site-and-photobucket.json
├── docs
│   ├── css
│   ├── general
│   ├── js
│   ├── README.md
│   └── testing
├── internals
│   ├── config.js
│   ├── generators
│   ├── mocks
│   ├── scripts
│   ├── testing
│   └── webpack
├── LICENSE.md
├── MAINTAINERS
├── node_modules
│   ├── abab
...
│   └── yauzl
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── server
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── logger.js
│   └── middlewares
└── yarn.lock
```

I am using react boilerplate for my app scaffolding. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions in the README are bad. You can require it just fine.

```
npm install --save exif-js
```

Then

```
var exif = require('exif-js');
```